# Android using contact action picker in application

Tags: android-contacts, android

I have a list of contacts in my application and I'd like to display a list of actions user can do with that contact (like call, message, email).

If you add contact to desktop using "Shortcut->Contact" you can click on the contact icon and be presented with a list of contact actions which you can use to pick an action.

Is there any way I can use it in my application? Like system api call or I will have to implement it myself?

Thanks!
Leonty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!
It's called "QuickContactBadge":
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_contact-badge/

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding of your question, you are trying to show an Options menu or a Context Menu on Long Press. Well if this is the case, it is very easy to implement.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) is a very easy and good guide for such menus. I hope it will work.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I needed.
I'm talking about very specific menu already implemented in system:
http://img651.imageshack.us/i/actionpicker.png/

I'm hoping it's possible just to call it giving contact data instead of recreating it on my own.